# como ordenar alfabéticamente un array sin el .sort

Tags: javascript

tengo cualquier arreglo pero me cuesta trabajo ordenarlo sin el método .sort de javascript.

y me preguntaba si había otra forma de hacerlo.

```
var frutas = ['guindas', 'manzanas', 'bananas'];
frutas.sort();
```

asi es muy facil, pero quisiera no usarlo.

Comment: [Aquí tienes 13+ alternativas a `sort`](https://khan4019.github.io/front-end-Interview-Questions/sort.html), además con explicaciones sobre cómo funciona cada método y con su código. Pero sería bueno que expliques el motivo por el cual no quieres usar el método que existe para ello.

Comment: alguna razón por la cual no quieras usar el sort?

Comment: tarea asi me la pidieron.

Answer (score 1):

Usa el método 'compareTo', a través de el que ofrece JavaScript podrás comparar objetos y cadenas de caracteres.

Luego de esto utiliza algún método de ordenamiento como Burbuja y comprar las posiciones.

```
var cities = new String("Paris   Moscow   Tokyo");
var string2 = "Paris Moscow Tokyo";
if (cities.compareTo(string2) == 0)
    return cities + " == " + string2;
else
    return cities + "!= " + string2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const arr = ['guindas', 'manzanas', 'bananas'];

const bubbleSort = (arr) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < arr.length - i; j++) {
      if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
        [arr[j], arr[j + 1]] = [arr[j + 1], arr[j]];
      }
    }
  }

  return arr;
};
bubbleSort(arr);
```

Comment: existen varios algoritmos de ordenamiento este solo es uno de ellos llamado bubbleSort